# How to use sound-play module in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I tried to install several modules to play audio in node.js.
I've tried various modules, but none of them worked.

Among them, I would like to ask you whether the most popular module works.

The link to the module is here.
https://npm.io/package/sound-play

Here's the code that failed.

```js
const express = require("express"),nunjucks = require("nunjucks"),fs = require("fs").promises;
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const sound = require("sound-play");

....


app.get("/play", (req, res) => {
  fs.readdir("./musicBox")
    .then((filelist) => {
      const filePath = path.join(`./musicBox/`, filelist[count]);
      console.log(filePath);
      sound.play(filePath);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err;
    });
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

and index.html is

```html
...
<form  action="/play" method="get">
  <input type="submit" value="재생"/>
</form>
...
There's no error message when you click it.
```